# print("Hello " + input("What is your name?")) Can someone let me know why + symbol is used

Tags: input, symbols

print("Hello " + input("What is your name?")) Can someone let me know why + symbol is used.

I tried but I am confused a bit that why + is required.

Answer (score 0):

`"Hello "` is a string.
`input("...")` is a string.

`+` means glue two strings together, as in `"Hi" + "!" = "Hi!"`

If there wouldn't be a `+` and python would have to guess what to do, it would lead to unpredictable behavior, when you would want one thing and python would do something else.